# Why do Google Analytics and Sharepoint give different numbers?

Tags: web-analytics, google-analytics

I've recently (2 months ago) implemented google analytics on the master page of our intranet site (Sharepoint 2010) and have compared the figures from both, can anyone explain why they are so different and which are most accurate?

> Total page views       42,000 (SP) | 21,000 (GA)
>   Daily unique
>   visitors  3,800 (SP)  | 2,500 (GA)
>   Avg. # daily uniques   545 (SP)   | 354 (GA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The major difference in statistics between Google Analytics and
> SharePoint Stats comes from the method they use to track page views
> and visitors. Google Analytics uses a more accurate method by setting
> a cookie on the user's browser which means the user is most likely to
> be a real user as opposed to an automate computer program.

Read More about it on this [Blog](http://jensontaylor.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/blogger-stats-vs-google-analytics.html)

"I personally think" Some people use proxies to visit pages or robots that visit pages are counted by an ordinary tracker however Google they are deep into business and knows how to get exact accurate results :)

Hope it helped !!

Answer (score 0):

Could be because In google you might have less domains or multiple that you are tracking! you need to add them to the list is GA to track domains and/or sub domains :)